# Uso de palabra clave super en clases abstractas

Tags: java

Alguien me podría decir para que se usa exactamente la palabra reservada super en este ejercicio(se que se usa para llamar al constructor de la clase padre)pero no entiendo porque esta definido el argumento String nom en la clase padre siendo esta clase abstracta y no se puede instanciar... Estoy empezando en Java siguiendo el curso de pildorasinformaticas por si se preguntan que hago algo y no se como xD,Gracias de antemano!

```
package poo;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Uso_Persona {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Persona[] laspersonas=new Persona[2];

        laspersonas[0]=new Empleado2("Luis Conde",50000,2009,02,25);
        laspersonas[1]=new Alumno("Ana Lopez","Biologicas");

        for(Persona p: laspersonas){
            System.out.println(p.damenombre()+", "+p.damedescripcion());
        }
    }
}

abstract class Persona{

    private String nombre;
    public abstract String damedescripcion();

    public Persona(String nom) {
        nombre=nom;
    }

    public String damenombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
}

class Empleado2  extends Persona{

    public Empleado2(String nom,double sue,int agno,int mes,int dia) {

        super(nom);

        sueldo=sue;

        GregorianCalendar calendario=new GregorianCalendar(agno,mes -1,dia);

        altaContrato=calendario.getTime();

        id=idsiguiente;

        idsiguiente++;

    }

    public String damedescripcion() {
        return"Este empleado tiene un id="+id+" con un sueldo="+ sueldo;
    }

    public double damesueldo() { //Getter
        return sueldo;
    }

    public Date damefechacontrato() { //Getter
        return altaContrato;
    }

    public int dameid(){
        return id;
    }

    public void subesueldo(double porcentaje) { //setter

        double aumento=sueldo*porcentaje/100;

        sueldo+=aumento;
    }

    private double sueldo;

    private Date altaContrato;

    private int id;

    private static int idsiguiente=1;
}

class Alumno extends Persona{
    private String carrera;

    public Alumno(String nom,String car) {

        super(nom);

        carrera=car;
    }

    public String damedescripcion(){
        return"Este alumno esta estudiando la carrera de="+carrera;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las clases abstractas, aunque no se puedan crear instancias concretas de ellas, sirven para definir características y comportamientos comunes en una jerarquía de clases donde cada una de las clases que hereden de esta abstracta, no son otra cosa que un tipo más específico. Generalmente una clase se define como abstracta o bien porque tu programa no necesita manejar objetos de este tipo y/o porque dicha clase no tiene toda la información necesaria para realizar alguna que otra tarea (de ahí que además la clase `Persona` tenga el método abstracto `damedescripcion()` ya que desde dicha clase no tienes como conocer la descripción correcta que debes retornar).

En la jerarquía de tu ejemplo, tienes una clase `Persona` de la cual heredan las clases `Empleado2` y `Alumno`, que, al heredar de `Persona` comparten el atributo nombre, puesto que tanto un empleado como un alumno tienen nombre. Es importante mencionar, que este es un caso muy sencillo, pero `Persona` pudiera tener muchos más atributos. Si no se hubiese creado la clase `Persona`, tanto `Empleado2` como `Alumno` tendrían que agregar el código correspondiente para manejar el nombre. Entonces, como el nombre está (correctamente) definido como atributo de la clase `Persona`, como los constructores de las clases no se heredan y como el constructor de persona define que se le debe pasar el valor que se asignará a dicho atributo cuando se cree la instancia de la clase, es que es necesario llamar al constructor de la clase padre en los constructores de las clases hijas y pasarle el nombre.

La herencia en un mecanismo increíble para la reutilización de código, puesto que todo el código definido en una clase padre es como si lo estuvieras definiendo igual en las hijas. Tal vez en una jerarquía pequeña no se note, pero en una grande, y que requiera poder ser escalada, se nota y mucho.

Se que es complicado de comprender desde un inicio y más solo con una respuesta aquí, pero espero que te ayude.

Comment: Gracias por la edicion anterior por cierto,soy nuevo aqui...muchas gracias por la respuesta,super completa,pero aun no logro comprender que funcion tiene colocar el argumento en el constructor de la clase padre si esta es abstracta y como se sabe las clases abstractas no se pueden instanciar pero al quitar ese parametro veo que todo el programa colapsa

Comment: Como te comento en la respuesta, los constructores de las clases no se heredan, y las clases abstractas también necesitan constructores. Los constructores no son los encargados de crear las instancias de clase, son los encargados de inicializar los atributos de estas. Por tales motivos, cuando una clase hereda de otra, sea abstracta o no, en su constructor tiene que llamar al constructor del padre. En tu caso, el constructor del padre requiere que se le pase un `String` para inicializar con este el valor del atributo `nombre`.

Comment: Osea que lo de pasarle un argumento a un constructor e inicializarlo ahi mismo simplemente es por comodidad,para ahorrarse el trabajo de inicializarse en cada una de las clases hijas,creo que al fin lo entendi o eso creo xD...muchas gracias por la ayuda bro!

Comment: Esa puede ser una de las razones, pero generalmente lo que ocurre (en aplicaciones reales) es que los constructores tienen validaciones, alguna lógica de tratamiento de los datos, etc, por lo que realizar esas operaciones en los constructores de las clases hijas, contradice el sentido de la herencia.

Comment: Mira me surgio otra duda probando cosas... porque al cambiar el nombre del argumento del constructor de la clase padre y dejando el nombre del argumento del super como antes el programa sigue funcionando,no se supone que la palabra super es para llamar al constructor?

Comment: Te recomiendo que publiques otra pregunta explicado esto, ya que no lo entiendo y si seguimos debatiendo por aquí, van a cerrar los comentarios y mandarlos al chat para debatir, y tu no podrías entrar al chat.

Comment: Disculpa no sabia...aun asi gracias por la ayuda, seguire invetigando.